# Change the user running redis instance

Tags: redis

I'm trying to change the user that starts my redis instance? Currently is root.

`root     16705  0.0  0.0 133312  1960 ?  ssl  11:00   0:02 redis-server`

It is definitely not the best thing.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oracle Linux Server 6.7   /   Linux hostname 3.8.13-118.6.1.el6uek.x86_64

Comment: @Anonymous-SOS - Here you find a copy of /etc/init.d/redis-server http://txt.do/5b9tk